# php swiftmailer Message convert to \MailSo\Mime\Message

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm doing an integration between two applications and I need to start sending the saved Swiftmailer Swift_Message with a library that uses \MailSo\Mime\Message.

I don't need to create a full \MailSo\Mime\Message of the Swiftmailere Swift_Message just need to take the vital information like: subject, body, to, cc, bcc, attachments.

I been trying but all the parts really is confusing for me.

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: So you have a fairly simple problem, no code to offer and want someone to do all the work for you, is that accurate? if yes, do some work, provide code when *specific* problems arise.

Comment: I'm not asking for a implementation, just an exlanaition of how the parts works.